# Optimizing finding an endgame

Tags: algorithm

I'm implementing a game called Neutreeko (5x5 board, each player has three paws, game ends when one of them forms a connected orthogonal or diagonal line) and am currently thinking about the most optimal way to check if the game has ended. I'm storing the state of the board in a one-dimensional array and I only figured the brute force approach in which I just check each row, column and every diagonal line of lenght 3 and 5 until I find a hit. Is there any better way of finding the end of game in such scenario?

Comment: Did you already implement the check? Is it too slow? If not, don't waste your time, if you won't see a difference.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski - I know, I'm just curious as this method of checking is quite tedious and I reckoned there should be a faster/more elegant way.

Comment: Tedious for the computer? No need to worry there, computers can't feel bored. Tedious for the programmer to write? That's a valid concern. Perhaps you could post your code on the Code Review site, and they can lend advice for making it smaller.

Comment: If each player has only three pawns, just look there positions up in the array (linear search). Given the position of two pawns, there are only 2 positions for the 3rd pawn to make a win (right?). You can check that in constant time.

Comment: For this kind of tests you can use a [Bitboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) representation of your board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store the board as a bitmap (with position i, j stored in bit i + j*5), you can do the checks quickly.

For example,

```
x & (x >> 1) & (x >> 2) & 0x739ce7
```

is non-zero if there's a horizontal row of three.

```
x & (x >> 5) & (x >> 10)
```

is non-zero if there's a vertical row of three.

```
x & (x >> 6) & (x >> 12) & 0x1ce7
```

is non-zero if there's a diagonal row of three (on a diagonal like (0,0),(1,1),(2,2)).

```
x & (x >> 4) & (x >> 8) & 0x739c
```

is non-zero if there's a diagonal row of three (on a diagonal like (2,0),(1,1),(0,2)).

These kinds of bitmask checks are very common in boardgame position evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. What do you refer to as "x" in your code, though? Also - how does the board have to be represented for it to work - empty cells equal 0 and occupied ones equal to 1?

Comment: I tried filling a 25-element array with 1's and then performing the first and latter test and none of them returns success. What else may I be doing wrong?

Comment: OK, nevermind - it was a limitation of JavaScript (have to convert array to binary int first). Thank you very much once again :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to start by saying write what is easy to read, not micro-optimisations that you won't notice at run-time.

That said, this is how I'd do it:

It would be better to check the other pawns' positions relative to the first one, rather than brute forcing the entire board.

Further, since the board is square, you can work out positions much more easily in terms of the game board's elements since lines are made up of +1s, +4s, +5s, and +6s.
There would not be any decrements as we've found there are no pawns prior to a hit.

```
[ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4]
[ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9]
[10][11][12][13][14]
[15][16][17][18][19]
[20][21][22][23][24]
```

Say the first pawn was on 12. 
You would only have to check 13, 16, 17, 18.
Why not 6? Since you've already shown there's no pawn on 0 or 6 hence would have been pointless to check.

After all, if you hit one pawn and then failed, you can skip that player's remaining spaces since they haven't got a line!

It the next pawn hits, then recognise what line you're matching, and see if that line continues to the only place available (14, 20, 22, 24 respectively).

Further optimisations could be made in making invalid lines whereby it's pointless to check for anything other than a +4 or +5 from the last column, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While not as elegant or efficient as Anonymous' answer, one could also use a bitboard like this:

```
/*
parseInt("111",2) == 7

parseInt("1"
   + "00001"
   + "00001",2)   == 1057

parseInt("1"
   + "00010"
   + "00100",2)   == 1092

parseInt("100"
     + "00010"
     + "00001",2) == 4161

To win, a player's bit-board must represent a multiple of one of the masks; 
the multiple must be a power of two; and the mask cannot straddle both sides 
of the bit-board:
*/

function testWinner(board){
    var i = 0,
        masks = [7,1057,1092,4161],
        winner = false

    while (!winner && masks[i]){
        winner = board % masks[i] == 0 
              && !(board / masks[i] & (board / masks[i] - 1)) 
              && !(board & 17318416 && board & 1082401)
        i++
    }
    return winner
}
```